# CoreData crash NSTaggedDate objectForKey

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, core-data

I'm using CoreData in my iOS application, I have a function that creates NSManagedObjectContext per thread:

```
var contextDict = [Thread:NSManagedObjectContext]()

var context:NSManagedObjectContext{
    if let context = contextDict[Thread.current]{
        return context
    }else{
        let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        context.persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator
        contextDict[Thread.current] = context
        return context
    }
}
```

in the init i create the main one with:

```
contextDict[Thread.main] = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
```

suddenly i start to get crashes on this method(not all the time):

```
if let context = contextDict[Thread.current]
```

Crash log:

```
-[__NSTaggedDate objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8000000000000000
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSTaggedDate objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8000000000000000'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1b05b2d94 0x1a966c3d0 0x1b0727b14 0x1b05c91c8 0x1b062f9f0 0x1aa3c0b88 0x107919d00 0x10791c344 0x10790c220 0x10790ced0 0x107914bd0 0x107905814 0x1070ca3d8 0x107024e84 0x10799c520 0x10799e038 0x1079a60b0 0x1079a6df4 0x1079b3c74 0x20ff33ddc 0x20ff33b7c)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSTaggedDate objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8000000000000000'
terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any idea what can by the problem?

Comment: It seems that `contextDict` is a `Date`. Why? That's a good question, it's missing how you really keep the object alive. But it's unclear why you do this. It'd be better to create the context inside the thread, and that way it's for it, and always use `perform()`/`performAndWait()` to be sure to be executed in that thread. But if you're accessing the `contextDict` from another thread there might be some concurrency access issue.